# Mocking AmazonS3 listObjects function in scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, testing

Im trying to mock `listObjects` function in `AmazonS3` interface, in order to return specific objects when running tests without calling s3.

The code I want to test is doing this logic:

```
val objects = s3Client.listObjects(
      new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucketName)
        .withMaxKeys(2000)
    )

    val latestSchemaKey = objects.getObjectSummaries.toList
      .map(s => s.getKey)
      .sorted(Ordering[String].reverse)
      .head
```

I wanted to create a new `ObjectListing` and add `objectSummaries` to it, but seems like there are not setters for `objectSummaries`.

Is there something Im missing out?
Thanks for helping!

Looked into `ObjectListing` class functions and noticed its not possible to set objects :)

Comment: Mocking components provided by third party libs could not be the best strategy for testing in this case. Usually a client should be tested with a testkit provided by the lib or in an integration test. You can use localstack to create an integration test where you put something in s3 and then fetch it.